# What is the capacity of a BluePrism Internal Work Queue?

Tags: memory-management, automation, out-of-memory, blueprism, rpa

I am working in BluePrism Robotics Process Automation and trying to load an excel sheet with more than 100k records (It might go upwards of 300k in some cases).
I am trying to load internal work queue of BluePrism, but I get an error as quoted below:

> 'Load Data Into Queue' ERROR: Internal : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Is there a way to avoid this problem, in the way where I can free up more memory?
I plan to process records one by one from queue, and put them into new excel sheets categorically. Loading all that data in a collection and looping over it may be memory consuming, so I am trying to find out a more efficient way.

I welcome any and all help/tips.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue for RPA, especially if working with large excel files. As far as I know, there are no 100% solutions, but only methods reduce the symptoms. I have run into this problem several times and these are the ways I would try to handle them:

1. Disable or Errors only for stage logging.
2. Don`t log parameters on action stages (especially ones that work with the excel files)
3. Run Garbage collection process
4. See if it is possible to avoid reading excel files into BP collections and use OLEDB to query the file
5. See if it is possible to increase the Ram memory on the machines
6. If they’re using the 32-bit version of the app, then it doesn’t really matter how much memory you feed it, Blue Prism will cap out at 2 GB.

Answer (score 3):

**Basic Solution:**
Break up the number of Excel rows you are pulling into your Collection data item at any one time. The thresholds for this will depend on your resource system memory and architecture, as well as structure and size of the data in the Excel Worksheet. I've been able to quickly move 50k 10-column-rows from Excel to a Collection and then into the Blue Prism queue very quickly.

You can set this up by specifying the Excel Worksheet range to pull into the Collection data item, and then shift that range each time the Collection has been successfully added to the queue.

After each successful addition to the queue and/or before you shift the range and/or at a predefined count limit you can then run a Clean Up or Garbage Collection action to free up memory.

You can do all of this with the provided Excel VBO and an additional Clean Up object.

**Keep in mind:**
Even breaking it up, looping over a Collection this large to amend the data will be *extremely* expensive and slow. The most efficient way to make changes to the data will be at the Excel Workbook level or when it is already in the Blue Prism queue.

**Best Bet:** [esqew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269970/esqew)'s alternative solution is the most elegant and probably your best bet.

[Jarrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2428899/jarrick) hit it on the nose in that Work Queue items should provide the bot with information on what they are to be working on and a Control Room feedback space, but not the actual work data to be implemented/manipulated.

In this case you would want to just use the items Worksheet row number and/or some unique identifier from a single Worksheet column as the queue item data so that the bot can provide Control Room feedback on the status of the item. If this information is predictable enough in format there should be no need to move *any* data from the Excel Worksheet to a Collection and then into a Work Queue, but rather simply build the queue based on that data predictability.

Conversely you can also have the bot build the queue "as it happens", in that once it grabs the single row data from the Excel Worksheet to work it, can as well add a queue item with the row number of the data. This will then enable Control Room feedback and tracking. However, this would, in almost every case, be a bad practice as it would not prevent a row from being worked multiple times unless the bot checked the queue first, at which point you've negated the speed gains you were looking to achieve in cutting out the initial queue building in the first place. It would also be impossible to scale the process for multiple bots to work the Excel Worksheet data efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

This is may be because of BP Server as the memory is shared between Processes and Work queue.Better option is to use two bots and multiple queues to avoid Memory Error.

Comment: Thanks, but it kinda doesn't solve my problem completely. I've been working on a different approach but queues seems to be the better one. I am trying to call Garbage Collect hoping to fix memory issues that I get at runtime.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Excel documents or CSV files, you can use the OLEDB object to connect and query against it as if it were a database. You can use the SQL syntax to limit the amount of rows that are returned at a time and paginate through them until you've reached the end of the document.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you are making incorrect use of the Work Queue in Blue Prism. The Work Queue **should not be used to store this type and amount of data.** (please read the BP documentation on Work Queues thoroughly).

Solving the issue at hand, being the misuse requires 2 changes:

1. Only store **references** in your Item Data which point to the Excel file containing the data.
2. If you're consulting this much data many times, perhaps convert the file into a CSV, write a VBO that queries the data directly in the CSV.

The first change is not just a recommendation, but as your project progresses and IT Architecture and InfoSec comes into play, it will be mandatory.

As for the CSV VBO, take a look at C#, it will make your life a lot easier than loading all this data into BP (time consuming, unreliable, ...).

Comment: Hi @Jarrick, Thanks for your answer and correctly pointing out some of the things wrong with the approach. Although, this is nearly a 2-year-old question. To be honest, I was just starting out on my RPA journey and I've come to learn a lot of things that I was doing wrong with this robot. I acknowledge that the implementation approach is improper. On the other hand, even though it doesn't answer the memory management question, your answer is helpful nevertheless. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for that Ashutosh. Topics that weren't responded properly to, may lead to confusion, even though they're 2 years old ;-)